# Как менять изображение в реальном времени через SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, изображения, android-shared-preferences, настройка

Я сделал в настройках SharedPreferences, смену картинки, но она сразу не меняется, а надо перезаходить в приложение. Главное если на прямую менять по кнопке, а не через настройки, меняет в реальном времени, но естественно не сохраняет.

P.s Не знаю, может после смены изображения обновлять layout или обновлять картинку?

```
        // Это через Preference

            private void init() {                                  
        def_pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        image_cats = findViewById(R.id.cats);
        String text = def_pref.getString("main_text_size","Кот_1");
        if (text != null) {
            switch (text) {
                    case "Кот_1":
                        image_cats.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);
                        break;
                    case "Кот_2":
                        image_catsw.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_2);
                    case "Кот_3":
                        image_cats.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_3);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    // А это по кнопке

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            image_cats = findViewById(R.id.cats);
            int id = item.getItemId();

            switch (id) {

                case R.id.action_setings:
                    image_cats.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_cat:
                    image_cats.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_2);
                     break;
                case R.id.action_pes:
                       iimage_cats.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_3);
                     break;
    }
```

Comment: приложите код как вы меняете по кнопке и как в настройках

Comment: В приложенном коде НЕТ изменения через SharedPrefs, есть только восстановление состояния при вызове Init, как я понимаю - это и происходит один раз при запуске приложения.

Comment: А как тогда добавить чтобы и изменялось сразу?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Вот нашел еще один способ который сохраняет текст, но нужно такой же, только изображение. Этот способ, сохраняет любые изменения в тексте и при включении приложения они подгружаются.

// Например если сделать смену картинки по кнопке в реальном времени, то можно было бы этим способом подгружать ее при каждом открытии приложения. Но на изображение я такой код не нашел.

loadText();



private void saveText() {
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, nik.getText().toString());
        ed.commit();

    }


    private void loadText() {
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
        nik.setText(savedText);

    }
```